# Saving a Bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bit-manipulation, steganography

I am trying to implement a Steganography project for Android. I have manipulated the pixel values and created a new bitmap. Now when i store the bitmap into the phone memory or memory card using

```
//fo denotes File output Stream
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fo);
//OR
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fo);
```

and try accessing the pixels back using getPixels();

the values are reverted back to the original bitmap i.e. rather than the manipulated bitmap.
Can anybody figure why this is?

Answer (score 1):

```
File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741

Comment: There is no problem in actually creating the file, but the pixel values of the bitmap changes.Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: For example the bitmap values for red , blue and green were 8,8,15 but after saving the bitmap the values were 16 16 16.Can anybody tell me how i can prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is lossy, it can change pixel values when compressing. Use PNG if you want to preserve colors.