# Is it possible to create a new folder?

Tags: android, uri, directory

Is it possible to create a new folder for images (to be taken through my app) to be stored in, on the android phone? (Or SD Card as far as I'm concerned). I could name it what I like [Maybe the name of my app so the files are easily found] and then the images taken by launching the camera through my app will be stored there. I'm thinking it might have something to do with Uri's. (Just a guess.)

Comment: yes u can do it. you should start with how to create a directory in sdcard first, and then how to write images to it. simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");   
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

check this link  [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just use File operation for that..

```
File imageDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Images/"); // Path for location where you want to make directory, Internal or External storage
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
imageDirectory.mkdirs();
```

And in Application's manifest file put permission..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/YourAppRootDir"; 
File dir = new File(path);
dir.mkdirs();
```