# Android SDcard Permissopn denied while writing a file?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, permission-denied, user-permissions

In my application, while writing a file sdcard it shows Permission denied. But i give permission in sdcard. Please help?

Writing file code:

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File f = new File(sdcard, "/abc.txt");
            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();
            }
```

---

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you post your code as well as manifest file...

Comment: please post your manifest file also.

Comment: @info post full error logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add use-permission in AndroidManifest file, and you should better check if you can r/w the file use canWrite() canRead() before use it.

Answer (score 0):

it requires permissions in manifest file, add this line to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Look at this Question [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741)

Answer (score 0):

in menifest file add permission to write file

pls try with file name as below

```
     String filename="aa.txt";
String filepath= getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File Filseting = new File(filepath, filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your SD card is currently connect to your computer so it will cause problem. I get in this situation before. You need to unmount sd card first