# Android saving Bitmap to SD card

Tags: android, image, bitmap, alert

I have a button, 
and I want when I click on it the image gets saved into the sd card ( or the internal storage, as in htc one x we don't have an external storage like an sd card )

this is my code:

```
            sd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MpClick.start();
                File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Saved_images");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                try {
                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       bitMapToShare.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 600, out);
                       out.flush();
                       out.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

and how do I make a message appears in it it's written "Your image was saved."
like an alert but for 2seconds and then disappears

Comment: How about Toast.makeText(this, R.string.your_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

try this

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
   myDir.mkdirs();
   Random generator = new Random();
   int n = 10000;
   n = generator.nextInt(n);
   String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
   File file = new File (myDir, fname);
   if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
   try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

and add this in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Look at this answer [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741)

**EDIT** : By using this line you can able to see saved images in the gallery view.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, only one problem
that the album "saved_images" doesn't appear in the gallery
but using a file manager I can see it made a folder "saved_images"
and inside it the image I saved
.. how do I make it, save it in the gallery

Comment: @AhmedAl-ekrii you might be testing this on emulator, and emulator update slowly. Use media trigger before entering the gallery. You'll find the specified folder there.

Comment: no, I'm using my phone HTC One X .. 
what do u mean by using a media trigger ? ( I'm a starter, sorry )

Comment: It's ok, the problem is the gallery cache
for anyone that faces my problem, use this code, it'll work
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Comment: It's probably better to use a date stamp instead of random numbers, to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Toast message**

like

```
Toast.makeText(Your_class_name.this,
                    "Your image is saved to this folder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```