# How to save Bitmap image to SD Card/Device gallery

Tags: android, bitmap, save

**UPDATED**

I want to save bitmap image to the SD card/device gallery. I tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846108/android-saving-bitmap-to-sd-card) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114) . Code is working and i am checking it on emulator. Whenever i save the image, there is nothing in the gallery. Please help

Log Report

```
07-25 02:57:34.345: E/MainActivity(1249): Error in creating fragment
07-25 02:57:35.476: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 02:57:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1409K, 21% free 5888K/7400K, paused 46ms, total 73ms
07-25 02:57:51.955: I/dalvikvm-heap(1249): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.959MB for 1166416-byte allocation
07-25 02:57:52.085: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 6% free 6983K/7400K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
07-25 02:57:52.266: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 02:57:55.556: D/dalvikvm(1249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2621K, 34% free 5702K/8568K, paused 42ms, total 44ms
07-25 02:57:55.606: W/System.err(1249): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/MyFolder/storage/sdcard/MyFolder/ pic.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-25 02:57:55.606: W/System.err(1249):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-25 02:57:55.606: W/System.err(1249):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-25 02:57:55.616: W/System.err(1249):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
07-25 02:57:55.616: W/System.err(1249):     at com.example.navigationexample.MainActivity.saveImage(MainActivity.java:314)
07-25 02:57:55.626: W/System.err(1249):     at com.example.navigationexample.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:148)
07-25 02:57:55.626: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
07-25 02:57:55.639: W/System.err(1249):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
07-25 02:57:55.639: W/System.err(1249):     at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
07-25 02:57:55.646: W/System.err(1249):     at   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-25 02:57:55.646: W/System.err(1249):     at  com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-25 02:57:55.646: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-25 02:57:55.658: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
07-25 02:57:55.658: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
07-25 02:57:55.658: W/System.err(1249):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-25 02:57:55.666: W/System.err(1249):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-25 02:57:55.676: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-25 02:57:55.676: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 02:57:55.676: W/System.err(1249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 02:57:55.686: W/System.err(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-25 02:57:55.695: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 02:57:55.695: W/System.err(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-25 02:57:55.695: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-25 02:57:55.706: W/System.err(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 02:57:55.706: W/System.err(1249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 02:57:55.716: W/System.err(1249): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-25 02:57:55.726: W/System.err(1249):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-25 02:57:55.726: W/System.err(1249):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-25 02:57:55.726: W/System.err(1249):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
07-25 02:57:55.736: W/System.err(1249):     ... 23 more
07-25 02:57:56.056: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Save function
        public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

```
    String fname = path + " pic" + ".jpg";
    File file = new File (dir, fname);
    //if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Function to make folder in SD Card. I have called this after setContentView and call saveImage function when i want to save it

```
public void makeFolderInSdCard() {
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
    dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: have you created external storage in your emulator?

Comment: Yeah. i have used SD Card

Comment: is there any expection you are getting, just check your logcat once?

Comment: I have posted the logcat.

Comment: your logcat clearly says, file you are trying to use does not exist,  i see code for creating file is there, so the assumption i can make is you havnt emulated external stroage in your emulator.

Comment: i am using 128Mib for SD Card in emulator

Comment: check my answer which i posted.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the permission in manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Try after removing file.delete().

Comment: Did that, but no results

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your sd card after **setContentView()**as follows:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
File dir = new File(path);
if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();
```

Then create a new file as follows:

```
String s = path + "pic" + ".jpg";
File newfile = new File(s);
```

Then use the FileOutputStream to store your image. Hope this helps. Also, why did you use file.delete()?

Comment: Did it. But its still the same

Answer (score 0):

// Instead of this

```
   String fname = path + " pic" + ".jpg";
   File file = new File (dir, fname);
```

// use this

```
String fname = "pic" + ".jpg";
File file = new File (dir , fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your log file properly. It is showing "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/MyFolder/storage/sdcard/MyFolder/ pic.jpg".

Here "/storage/sdcard/MyFolder" is repeated, which looks like invalid path.
So Valid path should be "/storage/sdcard/MyFolder/pic.jpg".

Answer (score -1):

You need to set of permissions and features in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Add following in your AndroidManifest.xml

- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE – Required to store images

it should look like this:

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="14"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
>
> <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```
>
> ....

then you need a directory name to store your captured image

> private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "name of your directory";

then a file url to store image

> private Uri fileUri;

Also you going to use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT to specify a path where the image has to be stored
sample code below:

> intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

[click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) for more future reference