# what does it mean to delete a file on android

Tags: android, filesystems, file-management

Naturally I thought to delete a file means to remove it from existence. So when I do

```
File file = new File(absPath);
....//add content
file.delete();
```

I expect that no further operation can be executed on `file` or it would throw an exception. But how come I can still add content to the file such as shown here [Android saving Bitmap to SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846108/android-saving-bitmap-to-sd-card). So how do I delete a file so that it is completely gone? So that when someone go look through file manager, the file is no longer there? I am not in a position to test this now, so I was hoping for authoritative reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how come I can still add content to the file such as shown here Android saving Bitmap to SD card.

That code creates a new file after deleting the old one.

> So how do I delete a file so that it is completely gone? So that when someone go look through file manager, the file is no longer there?

Call `delete()` on a `File` object that points to the file. Then, do not use that same `File` object to write to the file again, thereby creating a new file, as the code that you link to does.