# Share a bitmap loaded in ram

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bitmap

is possible with Android, to share a bitmap not saved on the memory?
Or I have to save the bitmap to a file, read it and next attach it?

Comment: Yes you can save image in external storage see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053338/save-bitmap-in-android-as-jpeg-in-external-storage-in-a-folder

Comment: Can't I avoid to save to external storage?

Comment: You can save to internal storage search for the same

Comment: The problem is: can't I directly send the bitmap instead of saving to a file and read again it?