# Android save image in sdcard/signature, not in DCIM/camera

Tags: android, camera, signature

I got an app on which you can put your signature. I'm having trouble with saving the image. I would expect the file to be saved in sdcard/signature, because thats the folder i specified in strings.xml and the folder is created. But instead it saved the image to the DCIM/camera folder and not in the sdcard/signature folder.

I already read about deleting the image from the DCIM folder, so thats not a problem. But i would really appriciate if someone can tell me why the image is not saving in sd/signature

In onCreate this happens (external dir is just a name like StoreSignature for a folder to store the images):

```
 tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is the save method:

```
mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {        
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            boolean error = captureSignature();
            if(!error){
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mSignature.save(mView);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                String status = "done";
                File path = mypath;
                Log.i("info4", path.toString());
                String[] arr={status, path.toString()};
                b.putStringArray("status", arr);
                Log.i("info5", arr.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);   
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

finally this is where the folders are prepared (dont know if this had to do with is)

```
private boolean prepareDirectory() 
{
    try
    {
        if (makedirs()) 
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kan het file systeem niet vinden.. Zit de SD-kaart er goed in?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a directory
 * 
 * @return whether the directory is created or not
 */
private boolean makedirs() 
{
    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists())
        tempdir.mkdirs();

    if (tempdir.isDirectory()) 
    {
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) 
        {
            if (!file.delete()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Deleten is mislukt " + file);
            }
        }
    }
    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}
```

Strings.xml (signature values)

```
<string name="cancel">Annuleren</string>
<string name="clear">Opnieuw</string>
<string name="save">Opslaan</string>

<string name="naam">Naam</string>
<string name="external_dir">Handtekening</string>
<string name="input"></string>
<string name="title_activity_signature">Handtekening</string>
```

Is there anyone who sees what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your strings XML?

Comment: ofcourse, i'm adding it now. Only the signature part will do it? because my strings.xml is kinda big.

Comment: Use the below link. It will solve your problem

[Android saving file to external storage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage

Comment: Thanks, it works! Only had to change jpeg compress to PNG compress. I tryed that solution before and got a black image, but it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below link. First of all you should check weather external storage is available or not. It will solve your problem

[Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

check all the answers in this link

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Also put the permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```