# xamarin android application: how to get the Resources folder of my project

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin

How can i get the Resources folder of my project like Resources/Drawable
i need this to store Images on the app for later use

I tryed:

```
var Path = (System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Resources/Drawable");
```

But i didnt work because i use this in a .cs (Class File) thats defined in the map
App_Code how can i get the Resources map i think there is an much easier way to 
get this.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this? I'm in a somewhat similar situation. But in my case, I need to overwrite the existing resources in the drawable directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to store images you get from somewhere the runtime, you probably shouldn't be using the resources directory.  Instead, you should save them in a directory on the SD card, see this post:
[Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114)

Otherwise, if you're just trying to access resources that you've included while building your application, this Xamarin guide should tell you everything you need to know:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/