# Cannot find file in resource map Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios

I've got a small question about Xamarin studio. I'm making a application that connects with an Http Server. 
Now what i want to do is save the configuration in an INI file. 
This will look something like this:

```
[Configuration]
IpAdress= 192.192.192.192
Port= 80
```

Now i want to read the file but i cannot be found. How can i use this file thats stored in the resource folder.

This is what i use to try to read the file:

```
IniParser iniParser = new IniParser("Resources/Configuration.ini");
```

This function calls the Load function:

```
public bool Load(string filename)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    var content = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                    _iniFileContent = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
                    string currentSectionName = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var line in content)
                    {
                        Match m = _sectionRegex.Match(line);
                        if (m.Success)
                        {
                            currentSectionName = m.Groups["SectionName"].Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m = _keyValueRegex.Match(line);
                            if (m.Success)
                            {
                                string key = m.Groups["Key"].Value;
                                string value = m.Groups["Value"].Value;

                                Dictionary<string, string> kvpList;
                                if (_iniFileContent.ContainsKey(currentSectionName))
                                {
                                    kvpList = _iniFileContent[currentSectionName];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    kvpList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                                }
                                kvpList[key] = value;
                                _iniFileContent[currentSectionName] = kvpList;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

So again it cannot find the file that is in the resource folder, How can i make it that i can find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do isnt possible. Your trying to set a ini file in a resource folder but when you compile the project and run it on a android device you can't acces the file. This because the file is compiled into the APK.

What you need to do is check if the file exists, if so read it if not make it. 
This link could me helpfull:

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/file_system/save_documents/

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't looking for the Resources folder.  Instead check out this answer about the **Assets** folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768857/1858751