# How to save image base 64 in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I used to same the `firstName` in the `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
private String filename = "mySharedString";
private SharedPreferences someData;
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
Editor editor = someData.edit();
editor.putString("firstName", phoneNumber);
someData.getString("firstName", "NULL");
```

It works good. Now I want to save the `base 64` of an image that could be 4 MB

Can `SharedPreferences` be able to save base 64? or that size is large for it ?

Comment: 200 MB ? how large and high is it?

Comment: not a very good idea to do that, rather use sqlight or use server side programming

Comment: Sorry it is 4 MB. it was just a typo. sorry

Comment: @Saqib i do have a server and i get the image using web service. i ask because i don't want to get the image every time the user open the application. it is his profile image. i want to save it in local phone. Also, should i use sqllight for just saving image? actually my application is simple. i just need to save the first name and the image. there is no other data in my application

Comment: Then do save the image in main memory or SD card rather than preferences

Comment: @Saqib how please? please tell me the name of this feature and i can search the `android developer` website to read more about it

Comment: I guess the person below has given an answer, and I request him to elaborate a bit more to get your answer accepted.

Comment: I have given an answer but You can store this image in local SQLite database also.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee kindly, would you please give me an answer about saving image on sd card and retrive it ?

Comment: @Saqib which answer please? the ansewr of `soulreaver` ?

Comment: Yes answer of soulreaver

Comment: from server site? you can do this. but please clear me one thing you can only fetch images from server?

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee i can fetch and send images to the using using `POST` and `REST` web service

Comment: Ok you have already got your answer you told me. So dude go forward..... if you need any further help then ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to save in memory

```
public void savedImage(byte[] data) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    preview_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    final String newData = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageName.jpg"));
        outStream.write(byteArray);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("No File", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IO Error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: and the parameter to this function is my base 64 when i changed it to bytes array ?

Comment: just to be clear. the profile image will be saved in `ImageName.jpg` image right? Also, i didn't get you by saying `if it's already then whats the issue? just use the rest of the part.` sorry i am bad in english

Comment: profile image shall be saved with image named imageName.jpg, in your device memory not preference. If your image is already in Base64 you just use the part for saving file, as the answer above takes a byte[] data and converts it to base64, while you already have image in base64, don't u?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this. The file size of 4MB is way to large for `SharedPreferences`. SharedPreferences were designed to store private primitive data in key-value pairs and surely not for the files. For storing large files use Internal/External Storage and hold `Uri` to it in the DB.

Comment: I think this question will help me. thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage

Comment: See this link: http://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/Storing-image-URIs-using-Android-SQLite

Answer (score 3):

Considering your image is at path --> "/sdcard/test.jpg", see the code below

```
/*Get image into file*/
File image_file = new File("/sdcard/test.jpg");
/*Get absolute path in bitmap*/
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file.getAbsolutePath());
/*Instantiate Byte Array Output Stream to compress the bitmap*/
ByteArrayOutputStream bao_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
/*Compress bitmap*/
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
/*Get byteArray from stream*/
byte[] arr_byte_image = bao_stream.toByteArray();
/*Base6e class has a method name encodeToString using which you can get string from byteArray*/
String img_base64_str = Base64.encodeToString(arr_byte_image, 0);`
```

Now as we have string containing whole image in base64 string format, we can easily store it into SharedPreferences

Please let me know if there is any doubt in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's bad idea, but you can do this in such a way

```
Bitmap photo=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.addphoto);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
                 byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                 String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

and store this string ba1 to your `SharedPreferences`

private String filename = "mySharedString";
private SharedPreferences someData;
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
Editor editor = someData.edit();
editor.putString("firstName", phoneNumber);
editor.putString("ImageData", ba1);
editor.commit()
```

I think in this way you will save image in sharedpreferences.

Comment: my friend, thank you for answering me. i am not asking about `how` to save image. i am asking about `is sharedpreference able to save base 64 of an image that could be 4MB size` ?

Comment: please see my answer , where I have store this in string format. Though it's 4 MB you can, but it's not wise decision . you can save this image in local database .

Comment: +1 for you. thank you for your help. i found a question, witch is posted in the comments with the above answer, is helpful. thanks a lot.

Comment: I appreciate you help and support. I hope I can help you one day. best regards