# Android mkdirs() sdcard do not work

Tags: android, mkdirs

I want to make dir in Sdcard, and i do follow:

1. I added: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest.
2. I get root_path by: `public static final String ROOT_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Hello_World/";` and it returns
   `/storage/emulated/0/Hello_World` (getting when debug).

Next, I run this code:

```
File file = new File(Constants.ROOT_PATH);
int i = 0;
while (!file.isDirectory() && !file.mkdirs()) {
    file.mkdirs();
    Log.e("mkdirs", "" + i++);
}
```

I also tried both `mkdirs()` and `mkdir()` but it's showing endless loop in logcat (`Log.e("mkdirs", "" + i++);`). Sometimes it work, but sometimes not.
Thanks for you helping!

`Update`: I tried my code for some devices: Nexus4, nexus7, Vega Iron, Genymotion, LG G Pro, then just Vega Iron work as expected. ??!!?!?

Comment: Ran your code to get it install in the device. Now unplug from the computer and run your app. Instead of Log.e show a toast.

Comment: @HoanNguyen I tried but it not helps :(

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about the problem experienced.  Edit a sample of this "endless loop in logcat" into your question.

Comment: Clear your app data using the device settings and try what I commented above again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that cause by `Log.e("mkdirs", "" + i++);` command. @Hoan Nguyen: I tried clean data, reinstall app, change device (nexus4, nexus7, vega iron, genymotion) before, but it's still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this it will create a folder in the `sd card`

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/hello_world");    
myDir.mkdirs();
```

If you want to check that file exists or not use this code

```
File file = new File (myDir, file_name);
if (file.exists ()) 
   // file exist 
else 
   // file not exist
```

For reference look at this answer  [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741)

Comment: I wonder what is the different btw your sollution and mine? //it's still not working :(

Comment: It will create a folder in the sd card .. then what your expecting ?

Comment: I my code, i try to create a folder named Hello_World on sdcard too, and sometime it works, sometime not :(

Comment: Both `file.isDirectory()` and `file.mkdirs()` return `false`, so my `while()` endless loop.

Comment: did you checked my code really..??? you are not creating file properly . because of that it's returning false.. File file = new File (myDir, file_name); create folder first and then check either that was a file or not. check code properly in my answer or reference link..

Answer (score 1):

The error is cause by `&&` in `while (!file.isDirectory() && !file.mkdirs())` it should be `while (!file.isDirectory() || !file.mkdirs())`. You should also check if the media is mounted.

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        if (DEBUG) {Log.d(TAG, "createSoundDir: media mounted");} //$NON-NLS-1$
        File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (externalStorage != null)
        {
            String externalStoragePath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
            File soundPathDir = new File(externalStoragePath + File.separator + "Hello_World"); //$NON-NLS-1$

            if (soundPathDir.isDirectory() || soundPathDir.mkdirs())
            {
                String soundPath = soundPathDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
                if (DEBUG) {Log.d(TAG, "soundPath = " + soundPath);} //$NON-NLS-1$

            }
        }
    }
```

Cut and paste from one of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Thank all you guys, finally i found out the problem. The problem is in the `while()` loop, I replace by

> if
>   (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
>   && !file.isDirectory()) {
>   
>                  file.mkdirs(); 
>     }

Comment: Likely part of your problem was that mkdirs() only returns true when it creates the directory, and not when it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` as below...

```
public static final String ROOT_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Hello_World/";
```

And Check that SDCard is mounted before creating directory as below....

```
File file = new File(Constants.ROOT_PATH);
int i = 0;

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
      if(!file.exists()) {
          file.mkdir();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it still returns `/storage/emulated/0/Hello_World` and still doesn't work. By the way, i want to know why did you edited my post (i'm get hard to read) and -1 me? Tks again!

Comment: I saw and changed, but nothing change :(