# how to Save Public File in Android external storage

Tags: android, android-file

I am developing an android app in which I am downloading a pdf file from internet to the external directory.
I have tried in many ways but there is always an error.
I am listing my codes with errors serially below:

1.

```
String fname=title+".pdf";
loc="/sdcard"+"/"+fname;
output=new FileOutputStream(loc);
```

Error:

```
BookActivity(1255): /sdcard/Pragmatic Unit Testing in Java with JUnit.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

2.

```
File outputdir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String fname=title+".pdf";
loc=outputdir.getAbsolutePath()
output=new FileOutputStream(loc);
```

Error:
    BookActivity(1172): /storage/sdcard/Download/Node.js for PHP Developers.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I have this permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<!-- Permission: Allow Connect to Internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Permission: Writing to SDCard -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Please help me out what to do??
Also if you can please tell me how to save public files in internal storage.

also tried the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741

but again arror:

```
BookActivity(1319): /storage/sdcard/Apache Axis2 Web Services, 2nd Edition.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741

Comment: `loc=outputdir.outputdir.getAbsolutePath()` why is `outputdir` used twice here?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first error you're using a wrong path (I guess). Since the 4.4 version (I'm not sure) they changed the way to access to external devices.

You should write:

```
String fname=title+".pdf";
loc="/mnt/media_rw/sdcard"+"/"+fname;
output=new FileOutputStream(loc);
```

I think it is the right way.

I defined the permissions in my manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is it because of the emulator??
I have not yet tried it on the physical devices

Comment: Well, it was an important information that you didn't provide. Unfortunately I only use physical devices. But you can find more information for simulated sd cards here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard

and here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html

Answer (score 1):

1> To write data file to sdcard :-

```
private void writeTextFileToSdcard(File fileObj, String fileName, String fileData) {

        fileObj.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(fileObj, fileName);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            myOutWriter.append(fileData);
            myOutWriter.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2> To write Image to sdacrd :-

```
private void writeImageFileToSdcard(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/My_Images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image1.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Permission is mandatory

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: let me ask one thing, I saw in the google developer site that from sdk 19 we no more required the permission so I used the maxSdk declaration in the permission. does it require some new permission???

Comment: Yes permission is compulsory for all versions. Can you please share error log if its not working.

Comment: Only <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> this permission is require to write data on sdcard.