# How to save image in external storage from bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, storage

I am using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to capture image using camera. It works fine, But the problem is that image is showing in imageview after clicking but can not saved in external or internal storage. Here is my code for saving image in external storage.

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/DashBoard/");
        file.mkdirs();
        ticket = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DashBoard/Ticket.jpg";
        file4 = new File(file, ticket);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file4);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ivTicket.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Any solution ?

Comment: `It works fine,`.Are you satisfied with only getting a thumbnail if the original image?

Comment: Which problems do you have? Any errors or exceptions? Post the logcat.

Comment: Have a look at the value of `file4.getAbsolutePath()` and realise that you constructed an impossible path.

Comment: Yes i only getting thumbnail. but not getting image

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
 myDir.mkdirs();
 Random generator = new Random();
 int n = 10000;
 n = generator.nextInt(n);
 String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
 File file = new File (myDir, fname);
 if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
 try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
   out.flush();
   out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114)

**UPDATE**
instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` you can use your storage location as API level 30 and above Storage-policy is changed.

Comment: check if u have permission in menifist and runtime permission too

Comment: Thanks for your support i solved my problem by removing getAbsolutePath() function.

Comment: yes i was already mentioned you in my answer Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageWorker](https://github.com/1AboveAll/ImageWorker/blob/master/README.md) Library for easily saving bitmaps/drawables/base64.

How to Save

```
ImageWorker.to(context).
    directory("ImageWorker").
    subDirectory("SubDirectory").
    setFileName("Image").
    withExtension(Extension.PNG).
    save(sourceBitmap,85)
```

Easy as that. Contributions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow it -

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ())
      file.delete (); 
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT:** By using this line you will be able to see saved images in the gallery view.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                         Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114)**