# Can I save photo of android app on sd card?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-camera-intent

I'm building an app to take picture from camera but I don't know that I can save my photo of my app on sd card in avd android (my AVD: Nexus 5X API 26 Android 8.0). 
I took photo and showed my photo on my app but I can't find it in my folder I created for my app (in SDCard). Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add the permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and so you need to get your Bitmap.you can try to get it from the ImageView such as:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView1.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

you must get to directory from SD Card

```
    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// Next, create your specific file for image storage:

    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
//After that, you just have to write the Bitmap :

    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: > <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @eyllanesc hi , I want to add permission  but when send isn't show !

thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your help