# How to save a file in the external storage on Android 13 that is also backward compatible?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-storage

I want to find an updated answer that works from android 5/6/7 to 13 with less possible permission. I know there are answers like [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external) storage but those are very old.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand accessing and storing files on android better from the [google's official documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific), mainly app-specific storage vs permission requirement, i.e. if you want to save file which are app specific, you won't need permission whether it being internal or external storage, but if you want to access locations which are not your app-specific, you will need permission for both internal and external storage.

Also, this behavior of permission requirement has been adopted after a particular API level, so you can start writing you code as per your `targetSdk` version and keep including options down to your `minSdk` versions and have a common method for permission for reusing it wherever is required.