# How to get a picture from url site and store it to device?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to store images from url & save it in SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card)

I parse a xml file from web

and it has a picture url like this: http://xxxxxx.jpg

then I use a

> private String url_picture = "http://xxxxx.jpg";

I want to store the picture in to the device

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this code to receive image from an url. And if you check this link it tells you how to save it on sd-card [Store Bitmap image to SD Card in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844746/store-bitmap-image-to-sd-card-in-android)

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String str, Options options) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap bm = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = HttpConnection(str);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null, options);
        inStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Comment: i should pass what kind of options to the method?

Comment: I transfered url to bitmap, but I failed to compress it to file 

I found that the bitmap's width and high are both -1

how can i do?