# Save photo to memory card instead of local

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have the following code taking a picture and saving it. But I want to save the final image to SD card instead.

```
public class TakePhoto extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);


        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        writeBitmapToMemory("image.png", bm);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }

    public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {
            fos = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

Theres one bit that seems to be playing up. I'm trying to save to SD card but it falls over with an error: (pastebin.com/FHihS4Wv)

I changed `writeBitmapToMemory("/mnt/extSdCard/image.png", bm);`on my onActivityResult –
But it falls over with the pastebinned error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this question [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963535/975959)
You're getting it because you're trying to access a sub-directory using a`String` object rather than a `File` object

Try to pass to the function a `File` object to that specific image file, instead of a string containing the file name.

Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    File imageFile = new File("image.png");
    writeBitmapToMemory(imageFile, bm);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

}

public void writeBitmapToMemory(Filefile, Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        // fos = this.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

    } 
....
```

Edit:
It should work now, but I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks for this. One question though, i'm getting an error on the openFileOuput(...) now, the openFileOutput (as seen http://www.tiag.me/pics/error.png)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and help. I appreciate it. It doesn't error, but for some reason theres no image. I have my file set as 'File imageFile = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/image.png");'

Comment: Did you set the necessary permissions in the manifest?
Also, it is possible that it's something with the dirs heirarachy. check this answer for example on how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7844792/975959

Comment: Yeah I have, it was my own fault a copy and paste error. Thanks a LOT for your help mate, really appreciate it! - Tom

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind (i don't mind asking it as a new question if you do :)) - When it saves the pictures they're really low quality and tiny

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it, but the documentation says that png ignores the quality indicator (the 100 in the compress method) try changing it to Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG and play with the number (range is 0-100)